# Does anyone know an AppleScript to save Stickies note state?

Tags: macos

I have some Stickies notes on different Desktop spaces. The problem is, every time I have to restart OS X, because of an OS update for example, a Stickies note does not restore to the Desktop space it was on before restarting. Thus, I have to move every Stickies note for each Desktop manually and I have 9 Desktop spaces to deal with. Why can’t they remember which Desktop they were before restarting?

Does anyone know an AppleScript to save Stickies note state?

**UPDATE 1**
Now I have one!! I have created one myself. https://github.com/lucasribeiroufrj/sortStickies.
Unfortunately It still needs an external dependence (cliclick) to work.

Comment: I doubt an AppleScript already exists for what you're asking because the Stickies.app does not include an AppleScript Dictionary, which makes it much harder to do any scripting around, as this just leaves what's referred to a UI Scripting. UI Scripting can be very kludgy and will be further complicated by trying to program for Desktop Spaces, as it too does not have an AppleScript Dictionary and it's API is not well exposed and therefore not conducive to scripting as well. Not going to say it's impossible, because I haven't tried, however from past experience I know it's not going to be easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for comment. Yes, I saw what you saying. Apple is not helping us regarding Stickies's dictionary. But, since I really want a sorting algorithm, I am gonna make it anyway! :-)
As soon as I am done with it, I'll be posting the code for it here.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not find one, I have created one myself:

https://github.com/lucasribeiroufrj/sortStickies